# Matching instance records in a data set by specific value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, activerecord

I have a solution and it works fine but it's less than performant and it takes sometime to run.  Let's start with what gets returned from the initial two queries (both double joins):

The first set of data looks like this - let's call these `line_items`.  As you will see, `line_items` do not have a `dh_first_name` key/value.

```
 [
   [
    {
    pb_id: "133599.0",
    pbbname: "CUSTOMER",
    opl_amount: "101.0",
    ops_type: "P",
    ops_stop_id: 269802,
    ops_order_id: 133599,
    ops_driver1: 11,
    ops_delivered_time: null
    },
    {
    pb_id: "133599.0",
    pbbname: "CUSTOMER",
    opl_amount: "11.62",
    ops_type: "P",
    ops_stop_id: 269802,
    ops_order_id: 133599,
    ops_driver1: 11,
    ops_delivered_time: null
    },
    {
    pb_id: "133590.0",
    pbbname: "CUSTOMER",
    opl_amount: "79.0",
    ops_type: "P",
    ops_stop_id: 269780,
    ops_order_id: 133590,
    ops_driver1: 104,
    ops_delivered_time: null
    },
    {
    pb_id: "133220.0",
    pbbname: "CUSTOMER",
    opl_amount: "625.0",
    ops_type: "D",
    ops_stop_id: 269011,
    ops_order_id: 133220,
    ops_driver1: 62,
    ops_delivered_time: "2021-04-01T12:35:00.000-05:00"
    },
    {
    pb_id: "133357.0",
    pbbname: "CUSTOMER",
    opl_amount: "550.0",
    ops_type: "D",
    ops_stop_id: 269290,
    ops_order_id: 133357,
    ops_driver1: 92,
    ops_delivered_time: "2021-04-01T09:38:00.000-05:00"
    },
    {
    pb_id: "133219.0",
    pbbname: "CUSTOMER",
    opl_amount: "1267.06",
    ops_type: "P",
    ops_stop_id: 269008,
    ops_order_id: 133219,
    ops_driver1: 43,
    ops_delivered_time: null
    },
    {
    pb_id: "133577.0",
    pbbname: "CUSTOMER",
    opl_amount: "150.0",
    ops_type: "P",
    ops_stop_id: 269754,
    ops_order_id: 133577,
    ops_driver1: 94,
    ops_delivered_time: null
    },
    {
    pb_id: "133503.0",
    pbbname: "CUSTOMER",
    opl_amount: "79.0",
    ops_type: "P",
    ops_stop_id: 269592,
    ops_order_id: 133503,
    ops_driver1: 104,
    ops_delivered_time: null
    },
    {
    pb_id: "133643.0",
    pbbname: "HALLMARK CARDS BERMAN BLAKE",
    opl_amount: "79.0",
    ops_type: "P",
    ops_stop_id: 269895,
    ops_order_id: 133643,
    ops_driver1: 104,
    ops_delivered_time: null
    }
   ]
 ]
```

Now, let's take a look at our next set of data from the second double join, which is `line_stops`.  It will look something like this:

```
    [
    {
    pb_id: "133633.0",
    pbbname: "CUSTOMER",
    pb_net_rev: "250.0",
    ops_driver1: 59,
    ops_stop_id: 269869,
    dh_first_name: "FIRST",
    dh_last_name: "LAST",
    ops_delivered_time: "2021-04-02T13:07:00.000-05:00"
    },
    {
    pb_id: "133127.0",
    pbbname: "CUSTOMER",
    pb_net_rev: "1147.0",
    ops_driver1: 102,
    ops_stop_id: 268801,
    dh_first_name: "FIRST",
    dh_last_name: "LAST",
    ops_delivered_time: null
    },
    {
    pb_id: "133144.0",
    pbbname: "CUSTOMER",
    pb_net_rev: "650.0",
    ops_driver1: 71,
    ops_stop_id: 268836,
    dh_first_name: "FIRST",
    dh_last_name: "LAST",
    ops_delivered_time: "2021-04-01T14:38:00.000-05:00"
    },
    {
    pb_id: "133144.0",
    pbbname: "CUSTOMER",
    pb_net_rev: "650.0",
    ops_driver1: 71,
    ops_stop_id: 268837,
    dh_first_name: "FIRST",
    dh_last_name: "LAST",
    ops_delivered_time: null
    },
    {
    pb_id: "133188.0",
    pbbname: "CUSTOMER",
    pb_net_rev: "700.0",
    ops_driver1: 71,
    ops_stop_id: 268924,
    dh_first_name: "FIRST",
    dh_last_name: "LAST",
    ops_delivered_time: "2021-04-01T08:04:00.000-05:00"
    },
    ]
```

What I am currently doing is looping through both of them and matching them based off these `values`.

```
ops_stop_id, ops_driver_1, pb_id
```

If those three match, then I need to structure them under the specific driver's name, which can only come from the instances with `dh_first_name`.  This data structure, when complete, looks like this:

```
    {
    FIRST LAST: [
    {
    pb_id: "133599.0",
    pbbname: "CUSTOMER",
    opl_amount: "101.0",
    ops_type: "P",
    ops_stop_id: 269802,
    ops_order_id: 133599,
    ops_driver1: 11,
    ops_delivered_time: null
    },
    {
    pb_id: "133599.0",
    pbbname: "CUSTOMER",
    opl_amount: "11.62",
    ops_type: "P",
    ops_stop_id: 269802,
    ops_order_id: 133599,
    ops_driver1: 11,
    ops_delivered_time: null
    },
    {
    pb_id: "133536.0",
    pbbname: "CUSTOMER",
    opl_amount: "45.0",
    ops_type: "P",
    ops_stop_id: 269665,
    ops_order_id: 133536,
    ops_driver1: 11,
    ops_delivered_time: null
    },
    {
    pb_id: "133536.0",
    pbbname: "CUSTOMER",
    opl_amount: "5.18",
    ops_type: "P",
    ops_stop_id: 269665,
    ops_order_id: 133536,
    ops_driver1: 11,
    ops_delivered_time: null
    },
    {
    pb_id: "133522.0",
    pbbname: "CUSTOMER",
    opl_amount: "150.0",
    ops_type: "P",
    ops_stop_id: 269637,
    ops_order_id: 133522,
    ops_driver1: 11,
    ops_delivered_time: null
    },
    {
    pb_id: "133619.0",
    pbbname: "CUSTOMER",
    pb_net_rev: "550.0",
    ops_driver1: 11,
    ops_stop_id: 269841,
    dh_first_name: "FIRST",
    dh_last_name: "LAST",
    ops_delivered_time: "2021-04-02T11:41:00.000-05:00"
    }
    ],
```

What you will see is a blend of the two records, with the matching parameters organized correctly.

This is currently how I am solving the problem!

```
    merger = {}
      line_items.each do |lines, i|
        line_stops.each do |stops|
            if (lines.ops_stop_id == stops.ops_stop_id && lines.ops_driver1 == stops.ops_driver1 && lines.pb_id == stops.pb_id)
              stops_arr.push(stops)
              merger[stops.dh_first_name + ' ' + stops.dh_last_name] = (merger[stops.dh_first_name + ' ' + stops.dh_last_name] ||= []) << lines
            end
         end
      end

      line_stops.each do |stops|
            if (!stops_arr.include?(stops))
              stops_arr.push(stops)
              merger[stops.dh_first_name + ' ' + stops.dh_last_name] = (merger[stops.dh_first_name + ' ' + stops.dh_last_name] ||= []) << stops
            end
        end
```

This is just too slow and I think this line is the culprit:

```
(merger[stops.dh_first_name + ' ' + stops.dh_last_name] ||= []) << stops
```

Comment: If you fetched this data out of a database then  you probally should be doing this there and not in Ruby.

Comment: I was afraid that was the answer, but I'm just so much more comfortable scripting my way through it... but I suppose there's no real way to optimize other than to do it through the query.  I don't even know where to begin, as far as implementing logic via SQL queries.

Comment: I would have a go at and if it doesn't go well then ask a question with a schema, models, example of the data and the expected output.

Comment: Can you provide a runnable example for the JSON variant? It can be abstract, no need to habe all those properties that do not tell us much (obvioulsy they are important to your business but i don't care about pb_net_rev :-))

Or provide the schema and expected result? So we can help you do this in SQL.

Comment: Well, the expected result is the last code block, except I take it one step further and add any ````opl_amounts```` that have the same ````pb_id````.  Here is why this is confusing - I am pulling all of this data from a third-party DB.  I have two ways I need to calculate rev.  If there are multiple ````opl_amount```` attached to ````pb_id````, add them up under that ````pb_id````.  If there is only one instance with a ````pb_id```` and it has ````pb_net_rev````, then take that as is.  There will AWLAYS be a ````pb_net_rev```` associated with  the ````opl_amounts````, so I also removed those.

Comment: As in, if an ````opl_amounts```` exist, remove the unnecessary ````pb_net_rev````

Comment: I guess `stops_arr` is an array, right ? if true then i guess the culprit is the logic: `!stops_arr.include?(stops)`. How about change `stops_arr` as a Hash.

Comment: Yes, stops_arr is an array.  It's simply there to remove duplicates... it's definitely causing some issues.  Can you elaborate on your hash usage?

Comment: `stops_arr.include?(stops)` will loop through the array then time complex is O(n). Now if you create a `stops_hash` which will cache/check duplicate by check `stops_hash[stops.object_id]` (or somehow to distinguish between stops) with O(1).

Comment: Lam, can you show me a simple example of how you would use a hash to cache/check for duplicates in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complex of your code is `O(lines.size * stops.size)`

Here my proposal which has time complex about `O(lines.size + stops.size)`

```rb
def merge_key(stops)
  stops.dh_first_name + ' ' + stops.dh_last_name
end

# Note that hash_key code below maybe not good enough
def hash_key(lines)
  "#{lines.ops_stop_id} #{lines.ops_driver1} #{lines.pb_id}"
end

merger = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
stops_hash = Hash.new

# O(line_stops.size)
line_stops.each do |stops|
  merge_key = merge_key(stops)
  next if merger.hash_key?(merge_key) # since in your code, you not add dup stops, right ?

  merger[merge_key] << stops
  stops_hash[hash_key(stops)] = merge_key
end

# O(line_items.size)
line_items.each do |lines, i|
  if merge_key = stops_hash[hash_key(lines)]
    merger[merge_key].unshift(lines) # since in your code, lines add before stops, right ? 
  end
end
```